# Failed to create table that removes Chinese characters from a string

Tags: mysql

Failed to create table that removes Chinese characters from a string

```sql
create table xx as
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT('汽车检测仪 AUTO' USING ascii), '?', '')
```

am getting the error below

> Query 1: Cannot convert 'utf8' character 0xE6898B to 'ascii'

Comment: Why do you want to convert with the database? I think it would be easier earlier in the web application (e.g. PHP, NodeJS, or whatever you use)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+ version; you can achieve it using [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace)

```
CREATE TABLE xx AS
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('汽车检测仪 AUTO', '[\\x{4e00}-\\x{9fa5}]', '') AS nonchinese_character_column;
```